# What are the minimum permissions for EC2 Instance Roles for Spring Cloud AWS Autoconfigure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-cloud-aws

I'm attempting to stand up a Spring Cloud AWS instance (in Elastic Beanstalk at the moment).  The instance bounces up and down and on inspecting the log there are references to missing permissions such as:
(my IAM EC2 Role) is not authorized to perform: autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingInstances (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID:

Perhaps I've missed it but is there a documented example policy for the minimums to have the instance fire up?  My first use of the cloud aws framework. My goal is to have access to SES and SNS from a service access perspective (and of course startup reliably as well) and have a policy that provides least privilege strategy.  I can make this box boot with an overly permissive role so I know it's permissions related.